# Change name of given package on build

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a Java project compiled with gradle (Kotlin DSL build.gradle.kts)

I want to `Change in all of my Class present on src this occurence "v1_16_R3" to "v1_11_R1"`

Usualy a build my plugin with the normal version `v1_16_R3`.
But i have create another `build.gradle.kts` for the `1.11` version, for not duplicate my repository.

Regards,
Lucas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, a IDE will have some form of tool that automates this process.

For example, if you are using JetBrains IDEA as your IDE, [follow theses steps](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Finding_and_Replacing_Text_in_Project.html#replace_in_path):

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+H or select Edit | Find | Replace in Path from the main menu.
2. In the Replace In Path dialog, specify the search and replace strings, search options, and the scope.
3. Click Replace All to replace all matching occurrences or Replace to replace items one by one.

Answer (score 0):

When working with NMS/CraftBukkit in 99% cases you can't just replace the version `v1_16_R3` with `v1_11_R1` and hope that it will work. CraftBukkit loves to rename fields and methods, Mojang loves to add/remove parts of code.

The best practice is to make a separate subproject for each Minecraft version you are targeting and create some sort of abstraction just for nms methods for the sake of simplifying the migration process.

More about
subprojects: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html